# Get class name from id in the last apperance of that div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class='user user1' id='newuser'></div>
<div class='user user2' id='newuser'></div>
<div class='user user3' id='newuser'></div>
```

For getting class name from id  i can use `$('#newuser').attr('class');`

Here how can i get the class name of the last div whose id is newuser ?

***if id need to unique then how can i get the class name of last class named user ?***

Comment: same id's are invalid in CSS

Comment: Ids mus be uniq

Comment: @kukkuz your phrasing is confusing. It's invalid in *HTML*. It's perfectly valid to repeat a selector in CSS - whether the results are what you want is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert($("div[id='newuser']").last().attr('class'));
```

Or

```
alert($("[id='newuser']").last().attr('class'));
```

Above code will get the class name and alert it. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: most welcome :) . Its not good to use the same id in many fields. I would only use the above code if there was no other options.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `#new_user`, why don't you use

`$(".user:last-child").attr("class");`

Plus, just like the comment above, element id must be unique.

Comment: Using `.last()` appears to be faster (https://jsperf.com/last-child-vs-jquery-last)

Answer (score 1):

First `id` must be uniq for entire document.
Second you can select last element of collection using `:last-child` selector

```
$('.user:last-child').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

using vanilla js
`document.querySelector('.user:last-child').getAttribute('class')`